# How can I get arrays to be defined and usable in another function?

Tags: arrays, vba

Getting "sub or function not defined" error. This is broken into three parts, example function, code to generate arrays, and lastly a code to combine these together for calculation.

```
Function Example1(X As Double) As Double
    Example1 = X ^ 2
End Function

Function UseArray(N As Integer) As Variant

    If N < 1 Then
       MsgBox ("Error: input must be at least 1.")
       Exit Function
    End If
    Dim X1() As Double
    ReDim X1(1 To N, 1 To 2)
    For I = 1 To N
       X1(I, 1) = I
       X1(I, 2) = Sqr(Exp(2 * I - 1))
    Next I
    UseArray = X1

End Function

Function ResultsNow(NN As Integer) As Double

    Dim XX() As Double, YY() As Double
    S = 0
    ReDim XX(1 To NN)
    ReDim YY(1 To NN)
    For I = 1 To NN
      XX(I) = X1(I, 1)
      YY(I) = X1(I, 2)
    Next I
    For I = 1 To NN
    S = S + YY(I) * 5 * Example1(XX(I))
    Next I
    ResultsNow = S * WorksheetFunction.Pi

End Function
```

Comment: I would add the language in the title, to make it clearer. And maybe explain just a bit better the intro of the question. Ps I would replace the word break with split. Breaking the code has heavier meaning than splitting the code.

Answer (score 3):

You never call UseArray...

```
Function ResultsNow(NN As Integer) As Double

    Dim XX() As Double, YY() As Double, X1

    X1 = UseArray(NN)  '<<<<<<< execute UseArray
    S = 0
    ReDim XX(1 To NN)
    ReDim YY(1 To NN)
    For I = 1 To NN
      XX(I) = X1(I, 1)
      YY(I) = X1(I, 2)
    Next I
    For I = 1 To NN
    S = S + YY(I) * 5 * Example1(XX(I))
    Next I
    ResultsNow = S * WorksheetFunction.Pi

End Function
```

Also, add `Option Explicit` to all your modules.